# jQuery toggle nav syntax error?

Tags: jquery, css, responsive-design

I'm trying to make my nav toggle when in mobile view viewport < 768px
If the toggle button is clicked, toggle the nav ul.
It seems I have a number of syntax errors that I can't figure out.

Is there a way of making the function fire without having to refresh the page when the viewport is < 768?

```
$(function() {
        if (Modernizr.mq('(max-width: 768px)')) {
            $('.toggle').click(function(e) {
              $("nav ul").slideToggle("fast");  
            }
        }
   });
```

Many thanks,

Comment: I suggest checking the `max-width` *inside* the click handler. That way, the browser width will be evaluated upon clicking rather than on page load.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to close your `click` function.

```
$(function() {
  if (Modernizr.mq('(max-width: 768px)')) {
    $('.toggle').click(function(e) {
      $("nav ul").slideToggle("fast");
    });
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    $(function() {

        $('.toggle').click(function(e) {
          if($(window).width() < 768){
          $(".nav ul").slideToggle("fast");  
         }
        });
       });
```

use this code. your if statement is running when page loads. so if page loaded in more width than 768 you event does not register.